# Inject VM 'by navGraphViewModels' with params

Tags: kotlin, android-viewmodel, android-jetpack-navigation

Suppose I have some View Model with input params in my Android app:

`override val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModel { parametersOf(args.item) }`

But I didn't find the way to use extension of jetpack navigation on view models, that have input arguments, like this:

`override val viewModel: MainViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.nv_main) *???*`

But in the signature of `by navGraphViewModels` method there is no such input arguments like `parametrs` (like in method `by viewModel` ).

So, could anyone tell me how to call `by navGraphViewModels` if my VM have params? Or this is impossible ?